Allow Cross origin for two specific endpoints. ASP.NET Core
I have an ASP.NET Core with cors initialized like this:
private const string AllowLocalApp = "_myAllowLocalApp";
string[] corsEnabledOrigins = configuration.GetSection("CORSEnabled").Get<string[]>();

services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                name: AllowLocalApp,
                policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins(corsEnabledOrigins)
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });

And then:
app.UseCors(AllowLocalApp);

In this way as I understand all cross origins are declared in the configuration file. And no other origin can access my endpoints.
I want to enable 2 different endpoints to be accessed from any origin. How do I do this?!
For example:
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("confirm")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmAccount([FromQuery] string userId, [FromQuery] string token)
    {
    }
}

How can I enable any origin for the path: /Auths/confirm?
I tried adding the attributes [DisableCors] and [EnableCors], but none seem to do anything

The question is common and there are many solutions given.
1.Add another policy
const string policyName = "CorsPolicy";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName, builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

2.Keep your app.UseCors.
3.Add attribute on the controller
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]

There is also a way , which is define a default policy options.AddDefaultPolicy() and modify the middleware to app.UseCors()(no name).
As shown in the doc. https://code-maze.com/enabling-cors-in-asp-net-core/
You mentioned your attribute didn't work, how is your code like, follow the steps and if there are still questions, feel free to post them.
